# For what reason is there the php session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor directives?

Tags: php, session

I am clear on what they do.  I am not clear on WHY php uses probability factors to decide whether or not to clean garbage sessions.  Can anyone explain to me the purpose of these two directives?

From PHP docs:

session.gc_probability integer

```
session.gc_probability in conjunction with session.gc_divisor is used to manage probability that the gc (garbage collection) routine is started. Defaults to 1.
```

session.gc_divisor integer
    session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 100.